# Entropy change of the ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics

I think the work out in process one to two should not equal zero, so my answer is different from the solution,
I wonder if there is something wrong with **δQ=δWpwin** .
Please say something the following wrong ideas.

(Thank you for your time and consideration.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there is something wrong with δQ=δW

There is nothing wrong. From the first law

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

For an ideal gas, no matter what the process, any change in internal energy $\Delta U$ depends only on temperature change. The problem states the temperature is constant. Thus $\Delta U=0$ and $Q=W$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How about δQ=δWpwin (Q = Wpwin)?
This is different from the solution(Q=W).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. $W$ in the first law equation above is negative if work is done on the system ( work in) and positive if done by the system. In this example, the paddle wheel work is work in, so $W$ is negative. Heat in is positive and heat out is negative. In this case the heat is heat out so it is also negative. So the values for both $Q$ and $W$ in $Q=W$ are negative.

Comment: About energy balance：
The solution manual say  δQ -δW = du and du=0, so δQ=δW=PdV=0.
My solution is δQ - (-δWpwin)=du and du=0, so δQ=δWpwin = 200kJ.

Comment: There is no PdV work in this example. $W$ in this example  is paddle work a.k.a stirrer work.  PdV work is boundary work, i.e., work associated with expanding or contracting the system boundary. This system is a rigid tank, i.e, there can be no boundary work. So we have  200 kJ of paddle work in and 200 kJ  heat out.

Comment: SO,about the energy balance  in Gibbs eq is not same δQ -δW = du?

Gibbs Eqs: energy balance
(δQ)int,rev - (δW)int,rev,out = du
(δQ)int,rev = Tds
(δW)int,rev,out = PdV
so,
TdS = dU + PdV 

so (δW)int,rev,out = PdV, always boundary work, no other input work is included?

Comment: ref.Gibbs Eqs
https://upload.cc/i1/2022/05/22/623iv8.jpg

Comment: What does Gibbs free energy have to do with this? Also, I'm having a hard time following your equations, you need to use MathJax.  You are going beyond your original question.  As far as entropy goes, the change for the system is zero since the final temperature and volume is the same (thus the pressure is the same). But stirrer work is irreversible generating entropy. The generated entropy transferred to the surroundings is 200 kJ/303 K.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and professional answers and suggestions. I will try to learn MathJax.